# In the following code I write the Login API but when I print the user it's give me None result

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, django-rest-framework

In the following code I created a Login API but when I hit the request in Postman it's always give me error response. How to rectify the problem?

This is my views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import UserSerializer, RegisterSerializer, UserLoginSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from rest_framework import status
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login
from django.contrib import auth
# from knox.models import AuthToken
# Create your views here.
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

#Login Credentials
"//Create a Login API in Django?"
class UserLoginView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer
    def get(self,request,format=None):
        serializer=UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        # print(serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)); 
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            email = serializer.data.get('email')
            password = serializer.data.get('password')
            print(email)
            print(password)
            user=authenticate(email=email,password=password)
            print(user)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return Response({'msg':'Login Success'},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response({'msg':{'Email or Password Does not match'}},status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

#This is my serializer.py file.

```
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email=serializers.EmailField(max_length=200)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields= ['email','password']
```

[image]

When I hit the request then its always give me error

Answer (score 0):

Django default User model takes the (username & password) field for Authentication.

in your code, you tried to authenticate with (email & password) so it gives None on every login request.

try for Authentication (username & password) instead of (email & password) I mean change like this...

```
user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
```

Instead of...

```
user=authenticate(email=email,password=password)
```

If you still want to Authenticate with email then you need to Customize the Default User model

for Customizing Django User Model refer to the link [here](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/)

#### User Model Cutomizaion code is here...

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from .managers import CustomUserManager


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

In the above code this line `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email`' give permission to authenticate with `Email` field Insted of `Username` field